# how to activate internet tethering in iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, ios, tethering

I am using an iPhone 3G and surfing internet on it. I want to connect this phone with my laptop so as to surf internet on it, but my iPhone carrier does not support the internet tethering option. It is invisible. Is there any way to enable that option.

Answer (score 2):

it would involve jailbreaking your phone and using an app like MyWi